# given onClick={this.triggerFlyEvent} in my div that function is not calling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- i am using a `react-addons-css-transition-group` for my slider.
- using the when i click the top part i am able to show the bottom.
- but when i click the bottom part its not closing.
- so I tried to use the same functionality in another code which they have used for top part.
- i have given `onClick={this.triggerFlyEvent}` in my div that function is not calling, since its not printing `console.log("triggerFlyEvent--->player");`

```or-tag-here
**<div className="sports-player-question-answer sports-submenu-dropmenuContents" onClick={this.triggerFlyEvent}>
```

Comment: why you defined that function as `static` ?

Comment: @MayankShukla since that function is used several times to render the component

Comment: remove the `static` work and call that function by `this.renderContent()` it should work properly.

Comment: @MayankShukla hey if I remove static I am getting this error, can you tell me how to work with static Uncaught TypeError: ATHLETE.renderContent is not a function

`
<ViewWhole className="sports-player-question-title sports-submenu-dropmenuHeader"
                        banner="testing dsdcsdcdcdsds" 
                        bannervalue={ATHLETE.renderContent(jump, <div>dscddscsdcdsds</div>)}
                    /> `

Comment: instead of that use `this.renderContent(jump, <div>dscddscsdcdsds</div>)`, don't have much idea about static.

Comment: @MayankShukla hey it worked...can you tell me the reason

Comment: @texirv By using static you can't access the method with 'this' as it's not part of the instance of the class.
MayankShukla, good spot

Comment: @MayankShukla can you tell me how to implement this one ---> but when I click the bottom part it's not closing.